# I am trying to save a DataTable to SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy() but I get an exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sqlbulkcopy

Here is my code to save the `DataTable` to SQL Server:

```
SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
bcp.DestinationTableName = "Hawalas";

ListtoDataTableConverter converter = new ListtoDataTableConverter();

DataTable dt = converter.ToDataTable(hawalastoInsert);

// SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=SALEHI\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Exchange; Integrated Security=True;");

try
{
    bcp.WriteToServer(dt);
    MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Err"+ ex.ToString());
}
```

The `DataTable` contains fields which their values are date and time; while executing I assigned the date and time value as shown here:

```
string str = "01/01/0001 00:00:00";

DateTime datetime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
var uk = datetime1.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
string t = uk.ToString().Replace('/', '-');
                
hawala.FlagDateTime = DateTime.Parse(t);
```

Note: `hawala` is a class which we create object of that and we keep them in a List finally using

```
ListtoDataTableConverter converter = new ListtoDataTableConverter(); 
DataTable dt = converter.ToDataTable(listTobeConverted);
```

We change the list to `DataTable`

Here is the error:

[image: error]

Here are my DataTable DateTime values before saving to SQL Server:

[image: DataTableValues]

Comment: `DATETIME` does not support dates prior to 1753, only `DATETIME2` does. What's more, string conversion ought to be avoided as much as possible in favor of passing *actual* `DATETIME` values to the database, which is evidently not happening here (probably your `ListtoDataTableConverter` class is to blame there). Where you *must* pass `DATETIME`s as strings, you should use a format that is independent of language settings (`yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fff`).

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data or errors, data or errors should be *text* in your question, see the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That conversion code makes no sense: you start off with parsing `01/01/0001 00:00:00` then you `ToString` it, then replace the separators and parse again. What is all that for, and why don't you just parse it once? Furthermore, if you have a blank date, perhaps you should be storing `null` instead. Side point: both `bcp` and `con` must be in `using` blocks in order to dispose them

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks But Previously I was Using BulkInsert() it was working and I could import the Date time but as it was a method in ZDapper and that was a 30 trial Library So I Decided to change the library. ListtoDataTableConverter is a class only to change a list to DataTable

Comment: @Stu Sorry it is the First Time I Post a Question Here. sure Next Time I would